# Retrieve rows where column value is the same

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Working with `SQL-Alchemy`, and I'd like to implement some specific functionality I'm having trouble with. First, here's some context.

I have a `Review` table that resembles the following:

```
id user item    review_score
1  Bob  Bicycle 1
2  Jane Apple   5
3  Dan  Table   4
4  John Car     2
5  Bob  Table   4
.. ...  ...     ...
```

Now let's express the users and their reviewed items as follows:

```
     Bicycle Apple Table Car
Bob  1       N/A   4     N/A  
Jane N/A     5     N/A   N/A
Dan  N/A     N/A   4     N/A  
John N/A     N/A   N/A   2
```

I can then generate which items were reviewed, and their score for each person via a `relationship()` to the `Review` table and vice versa for `users` and their `items` using `sql-alchemy` example:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    userid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    reviews = relationship('Review', backref='user')
```

This is great for allowing be to have on-the-fly looks for reviews per user with a simple member access: `user.reviews`.

Here's how my `Review` model looks like:

```
class Review(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'reviews'
     reviewid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
     userid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.userid'), nullable=False)
     itemid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.itemid'), nullable=False)
     review_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Now I am iterating through every single item in a nested loop to see which users rated both `items_i` & `items_j` (*current implementation below which I am not satisfied with; but works*):

```
for item_i in Item.query.all():
    users_i = {review.userid : review.review_score for review in item_i.reviews}
    for item_j in Item.query.all():
        users_j = {review.userid: review.review_score for review in item_j.reviews}

        # There must be a better way to get the users that reviewed both via the SQL-Alchemy query() API.
        users_that_rated_both_items = users_i.keys() & users_j.keys()
        if users_that_rated_both_movies:
            # I need these two vectors below for future computations.
            reviews_i = [review.review_score for review in item_i.reviews if review.userid in users_that_rated_both_movies]
            reviews_j = [review.review_score for review in item_j.reviews if review.userid in users_that_rated_both_movies]

           # I do more computations here...
```

I need essentially build up pairs of reviews for and `item_i` and `item_j` per user.

**A very simple way to look at what I'm trying to do is as follows:**

Get me the reviews for both items where they share the same users (*thus the lengths of the reviews will be the exact same as they share the same users*): `len(item_i.reviews) == len(item_j.reviews)`

**Is there a way to extract this data using SQL-Alchemy in a more idiomatic way?** As opposed to my current way which involves me getting the intersection of `userid`'s using python's `set` built-in.

Thanks.

Comment: These two loops can also have the same item like i = bicycle and j=bicycle?

Comment: Yes, so there's going to be a comparison between the same item in certain iterations @AmitTripathi.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @univerio SQLite